# Python reading xml inner tags

Tags: python, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child1>
        <details id="1">
         <name ab="1">Ram</name>
         <age ab="2">45</age>
         <phone>
            <phone1>777777777</phone1>
        </phone>    
    </child1>    
        </details> 
    <child2>
        <details id="2">
            <name ab="3">kiran</name>
            <age ab="4">57</name>
            <phone>
                <phone1>888888888</phone1>
            </phone>    
        </details>
    <child2>
</parent>
```

> if I given the input 2 it should return the details of child2 ie,
>
> the o/p should be
>
> details id="2"
>
> name ab 3 kiran age ab  4  57 phone 888888888888
>
> if I given the input 1 it should return the details of child1 and so on.

Comment: Homework? Or assignment?

Comment: Assignment related with automation

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Try to code yourself first, and then come back here if you are not able to, or have encountered errors. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

my_xml = 'some_xml.xml'

tree = ET.parse(my_xml)

root = tree.getroot()

id = str(input('Enter id: '))

for element in root:
if element.tag == 'child' + id:
    details = element.find('details')
    for detail in details:
        if detail.tag == 'phone':
            continue
        else:
            print('{} : {}'.format(detail.tag, detail.text))
    phones = details.find('phone')
    for phone in phones:
        print('{} : {}'.format(phone.tag, phone.text))
```

The xml is in file `some_xml.xml` located in the same directory as your python code. By the way, your xml file is not correct. It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child1>
        <details id="1">
         <name ab="1">Ram</name>
         <age ab="2">45</age>
         <phone>
            <phone1>777777777</phone1>
         </phone>    
        </details> 
    </child1>    
    <child2>
        <details id="2">
            <name ab="3">kiran</name>
            <age ab="4">57</age>
            <phone>
                <phone1>888888888</phone1>
            </phone>    
        </details>
    </child2>
</parent>
```

Fix yours and should work fine.

Note that the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module is not secure against maliciously constructed data as stated in the docs.

Comment: I tried like this, but how can we fetch all the contents under <child1>....</child1> if the input is 1

Comment: @Sudharshjasmine I edited the answer. It should work.